# Use column value as index of another column

Tags: r

i want to replace the value of a column in a data frame with a value of another column. The latter column should be referenced by using the value of a third column as an index.

```
  A B C
1 1 3 2
2 8 5 2
```

For example, the value of column A shall be replaced with the column at index C of the same row (here column B). Column B can not be targeted directly, because position and name are different in each row.

```
  A B C
1 3 3 2
2 5 5 2
```

I tried to use `df[,df$C] <- df$A`, but then he whole column C is used as a vector. Instead, only the vector's value at index == row number should be used, but i cannot figure out a solution.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `row/column` indexing.  Create a `matrix` of row index (`seq_len(nrow(df))`) with the column index (from 'C' column), use that to extract the values of the dataset and assign it to 'A'

```
m1 <- cbind(seq_len(nrow(df)), df$C)
df$A <- df[m1]
df
#  A B C
#1 3 3 2
#2 5 5 2
```

#### data

```
df <-  structure(list(A = c(1L, 8L), B = c(3L, 5L), 
  C = c(2L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to `unlist` your `data.frame` and take a subset of data from resulting vector using the vector names:

```
dat[, "A"] <- unlist(dat)[paste0(colnames(dat)[dat$C], 1:nrow(dat))]

dat

#   A B C
# 1 3 3 2
# 2 5 5 2
```